# Can I insert =roundup formula inside =if formula Value_if_false output

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on altering a curriculum accreditation tracking spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet is designed to attribute one credit to a student's file per week of course-work, based off of the calendar start and end dates listed in another tab.

However, I am running into the issue of past quarters that had 12-week programs spread out over a 14-week period.

My spreadsheet is calculating that they have 14 credits from the course they should have only 12 for. 12 is the most credits that our courses can offer, so I am trying to set a cap for the formula of `12`.

```
My existing formula is: `=ROUNDUP((E52-D52)/7)`

My attempted edit is: `=IF(=ROUNDUP((E52-D52)/7))>12,"12","=ROUNDUP((E52-D52)/7)"`
```

My goal is for the new formula to override the data if the =roundup formula result exceeds `12`. If the formula result exceeds `12`, I want the `=if formula` to insert `12` in the place of the higher number.

I have tried multiple different variations of the above-listed attempt and it keeps just resulting in an error message.

Is what I'm attempting to do even possible? And is it the most efficient way to put a credit cap on my formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=min(12,ROUNDUP((E52-D52)/7))
```

Comment: That would work in principle; however, we have students listed in the spreadsheet tab who have not yet enrolled in this specific class for this course. Each class has its own tab with its own credit calculation formulas. All students in the broader course are listed in each tab. So, doing that formula gives all students 12 credits, even if they took a variation of the class that was only 10 weeks or even if they didn't take it at all. Thank you though!

Comment: It just imposes a cap of 12. bit confused on how it can give full 12 credits for not yet enrolled: `min(12,0) = 0` OR someone with 10 week credits: `min(12,10) = 10`

Comment: I can't get it to both set a cap on the 14 credit errors without altering the numbers lower than 12. But, I might just escalate this to someone who knows what they're doing lol

Comment: If possible please do share a sample sheet with demo data duplicating this scenario so that we can have a clear picture to work it out

Comment: I believe I worked out the issue. Rookie mistake, in my testing to see if it worked for other cells, i kept the same reference cells in my roundup equation rather than changing them to the relevant cells for the resulting cell I wanted to test